# TrainCascade stuck on getting new negatives

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working with OpenCV 2.4.7 on windows. I'm using TrainCascade to train a new Haar cascade for eyeglasses using the following command:

```
opencv_traincascade -data trainCascade20 -vec vector3.vec -bg infofile3.txt -numStages 40 -minHitRate 0.999  maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 170 -numNeg 1000 -w 20 -h 20 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024
```

It's stuck (or progressing very slow) on stage 24 on the phase of getting new negatives. The negative images file "infofile3.txt" contains about 12K negative image.

Can someone please explain why it's progressing so slowly and what can I do make it progress (a lot) faster?

Thanks in advance,

Gil.

Comment: How many hours/days have it been? Just wanna know how slow you are talking about.

Comment: @rockinfresh, it's been "getting new negatives" for about a 24 hours

Answer (score 4):

Around 24 hours sounds normal to me. Haar training can actually take up to days depending on size and number of samples. And of course on the computer as well. The longest my training took was approximately a week for hand detection.

If you are really worried, to check whether the haar training is still on-going, you can try to generate an intermediate haar cascade xml file, from the data available. If you are able to generate the xml file, it would show that it's still running(albeit slow) and not stuck.

How to improve the haar training speed, the only solution I know or used before is "paralleling"

A quick search on google about that leads to a few link, here's one of them: http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/06/parallel-world-of-opencv/

I have used such methods, and it's pretty efficient in cutting the time taken to train the Haar Cascade. So hope this method suits you well. Do try my method of generating an immediate xml file from the current data available first though. If there is any needs, do comment, I try get back to you soon. Cheers.